# Vectorizing a comparison in numpy

Tags: numpy, comparison, broadcast

How can I vectorize this loop in NumPy? It uses sampling from NumPy's `binomial()` function to estimate the probability that out of 55 events exactly `m` of a particular type occur, where the probability of `m` occuring is 5%; ie it estimates 55Cm.(0.05)^m.(0.95)^(55-m). where 55Cm = 55!/(m!.(55-m)!)

```
import numpy as np
M = 7
m = np.arange(M+1)
ntrials = 1000000
p = np.empty(M+1)
for r in m:
    p[r] = np.sum(np.random.binomial(55, 0.05, ntrials)==r)/ntrials
```

Comment: It's nice if you write a short description of what your code is actually doing in mathematical terms.

Comment: cant this be solved purely analytical, instead of numerically?

Comment: Yes, of course - see the formula in the question, for example. This is a demonstration of random sampling from a distribution.

Comment: Vectorizing probably isn't going to buy you very much; the time to compute 1M random numbers is going to dwarf the loop overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the equivalent code:

```
p = np.zeros(M+1)
print p
```

I imagine you didn't intend for your output to always be all zero, but it is!  So the first thing to do is add a `dtype=float` argument to your `np.sum()` call.  With that out of the way, we can vectorize the whole thing like this:

```
samples = np.random.binomial(55, 0.05, (ntrials, M+1))
p = np.sum(samples == m, dtype=float, axis=0) / ntrials
```

This produces an equivalent, though not identical, result.  The reason is that the random number generation is done in a different sequence, so you will get an answer which is "correct" but not identical to the old code.  If you want the identical result to before, you can get that by changing the first line to this:

```
samples = p.random.binomial(55, 0.05, (M+1, ntrials)).T
```

Then you draw in the same order as before, with no real performance penalty.

Comment: Thanks - I'm on Python 3 (despite the impression my print statement might have given), so the dtype isn't an issue. Is there a way of doing it without storing such a large array as `samples`?

Comment: I don't know.  What's the real problem you're trying to solve here?  CPU time too slow?  Memory too big?  At some point you may be better off writing some C or C++ code and calling that.

Comment: It's just a demonstration, but I'd like to be as efficient as possible: the current solutions sample `ntrials` times for each probability and store the values when they only need to be counted.